# Solutions for integer $n$, given $ \exp(m-\frac{2}{\pi}n)=n^{b/{\pi}}. $

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, inequality, numerical-methods

Let $m, n$ be integers. Let $b \in \mathbb R$.

Solve the following equation for $n$.

$$
\exp(m-\frac{2}{\pi}n)=n^{b/{\pi}}.
$$

Thank you.

Comment: In general there is no solution to this problem in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: It seems unlikely that you would have been asked this question.

Comment: @Mack: Welcome to MSE! you list numerical methods, is that what you are looking for as opposed to a closed form solution (not typically possible for problems like this). It also helps to show what you have tried so responders can provide better guidance. Regards

Comment: A solution can perhaps be given in terms of the Lambert-W function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's play around and see what happens.

We have
$\exp(m-\frac{2}{\pi}n)=n^{b/{\pi}}$,
or
$\exp(m)/\exp(n)^{2/\pi}=n^{b/{\pi}}$.

Raise to the $\pi$ power and we get
$\exp(m\pi)/\exp(n)^{2}=n^{b}$
or
$\exp(m\pi)= n^b e^{2n}$,
or
$e^{m\pi} = e^{b \ln n} e^{2n}$
or
$m\pi = b \ln n + 2n$.

If $m$ and $n$ are integers,
it seems very unlikely to me
that this would have a solution
unless $b$ were chosen to make this true
for some $m$ and $n$.

I don't see how to go further
without using the W-function.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for $n$ is
$$n = \frac{b}{2} {\rm W}\left(\frac{2}{b} \exp\left(\frac{m\pi}{b}\right)\right)$$\
where $W$ is (a branch of) the Lambert W function.
However, the question is rather strange, because it says $n$ is an integer.
The solution will only be an integer for very special values of $m$ and $b$.
It would make more sense to solve for $b$ in terms of $m$ and $n$:

$$ b = \frac{\pi m - 2 n}{\log n}$$
if $n$ is a positive integer.  If $n$ is a negative integer, you'll want $b/\pi$ to be an even integer...